# UITableViewCell disclosure indicator disappears on scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom tableViewCell with some subviews defined in a prototype cell in a storyboard. In the storyboard I set the Accessory to Disclosure Indicator, but when scrolling (when cells are reused) the indicator disappears.

I tried to set it in code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

It did not work as well. But I found a working solution, a very weird solution:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

I don't know why this can fix anything, but it works for me. Can anyone tell me why or if there is an other problem/fix?

**UPDATE:**

How i get the reusable cell:

```
ActivityWeekCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

I also tried:

```
ActivityWeekCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[ActivityWeekCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

}
```

Comment: Can you show the part where you reuse cells ?

Comment: Have you tried using another Identifier ? Do you want a disclosure indicator for every cell ?

Comment: Yes, I want it for every cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this variant:

```
ActivityWeekCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[ActivityWeekCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```